# How to display employee name column using group by clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Hello I have two tables **Employee** and **Department**. In employee I have empid,firstName, salary,Department_ID, in department i have deptid and deptname. I want to show the highest salaried employee name from each department with salary.
I done with the following code

```
select  MAX(E.Salary),D.Name from Employee as E JOIN Department As D
ON e.Department_ID = D.Department_ID
GROUP BY D.Name
```

It is giving from only department table(i didn't include the E.FirstName here). When I write the query like below

```
select E.FirstName MAX(E.Salary),D.Name from Employee as E JOIN Department As D
ON e.Department_ID = D.Department_ID
GROUP BY D.Name
```

giving an error that

> **E.FirstName**  is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

How to modify this to show employee name also?

When I add the E.FirstName also in the group by clause I am getting following out put.

> ### FirstName Salary DepartmentName
>
> BAKER     1400.00 Operations
>
> Allen      5400.00    Research
>
> Smith      1800.00    Research
>
> Dennis     4500.00    Sales
>
> Mihir      7500.00    Sales
>
> WARK       8000.00    Sales

I want to display only Max salaried employees with their departments and salaries.

Answer (score 0):

Add E.FirstName to the GroupBy. A column in the Select statment must be accounted for in the GroupBy or another aggregate.  The answer is actually in the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
select E.FirstName MAX(E.Salary),D.Name from Employee as E JOIN Department As D
ON E.Department_ID = D.Department_ID
GROUP BY D.Name,E.FirstName
```

As the logic goes.This should work.If still you are getting an error. Please post the error. Else post the output.